# How do you create a sheet that follows the macOS sheet style in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to replicate the sheet style that most macOS apps use, but where I'm stuck is making the buttons wide and having one highlighted blue as a suggestion. This is probably explained best through pictures:

Here's what I want:

[Picture of a sheet from Xcode asking if I'd like to delete File.swift with 3 large buttons, one of which is highlighted blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8DvT.png)

Here's where I am currently:

[Picture of a sheet from my app asking if you'd like to reset the generator with two small grey buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqpvw.png)

And here's my code: (minus some variables not relevant to the sheet)

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $confirmReset) {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Image("sheeticon")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 72, height: 72)
        Text("Confirm Reset")
            .font(.title2)
        Text("Are you sure you want to reset the generator?")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal, 4)
        Button(action:{
            /* Resets some variables first, removed to make this easier to read */
            confirmReset = false
            NSApp.mainWindow?.endSheet(NSApp.keyWindow!)
        }) {
            Text("Confirm")
        }
        .controlSize(.large)
        Button(action:{
            confirmReset = false
            NSApp.mainWindow?.endSheet(NSApp.keyWindow!)
        }) {
            Text("Cancel")
        }
        .controlSize(.large)
    }
    .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
}
```

How would I got about making my buttons look like the ones used in Xcode (and most other macOS apps)? I've tried searching through any similar question I could find and any documentation I could find but I haven't had any luck so far.

**Extra detail I forgot:** I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.6 using Xcode 13

Comment: Any reason you’re not using Alert instead of Sheet?

Comment: @Paulo If you mean `alert(_:isPresented:actions:message:)` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:actions:message:)-6awwp), it's because that isn't available in macOS 11. Otherwise I would since it looks a lot easier.

Comment: You can still use the old deprecated version. I’m pretty sure I’m using it in a personal project. In relation to making the button show as blue. Have you tried .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)

Comment: Ah ok. Wasn't aware that there was another version. I'll give that version a try then and see if that does what I want to.